# added table to database now I need to pull that data out to display

Tags: php, mysql

So I added a small table to a database for a small project per se. Now I need help pulling that data out and displaying it correctly.

```
Table info
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab_dimensions` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `length` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `height` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `width` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `offset` int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

first piece of data I have

```
        INSERT INTO `tab_dimensions` (`id`, `length`, `height`, `width`,      `offset`) VALUES
        (56301, 600, 255, 183, 480);
```

So that is the basic layout of it. I have started with

```
    $sql = 'SELECT id, length, width, height, offset FROM tab_dimensions';
```

But am having trouble with what goes next. Sorry a newbie here trying to figure it out and learn.

Thanks in advance!

Update-
I this is a existing DB that I am adding to so the connection is not needed it already has one as $db

I am trying to use this data to populate a mouseover image mapping, so I only need to pull data and then use my existing table to display it.

```
    <div id="hauler-pole" style="display:none;">
      <table border="0" width="300">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>front</strong></td>
            <td>Length: </td>
            <td>Width: </td>
            <td>Height: </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Rear</strong></td>
            <td>Length: </td>
            <td>Width: </td>
            <td>Height: </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

So if i mouse over id# 56301 that data is displayed only in the table.

Comment: I am still stuck on this one if anyone can help out, please.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, length, width, height, offset FROM tab_dimensions";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"];
        echo "length: " . $row["length"];
        echo "width: " . $row["width"];
        echo "height: " . $row["height"];
        echo "offset : " . $row["offset"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Ok but what if already have a format for the display in a mouseover table and I am trying to pull a specific row for a certain mouseover? Does that make sense? Basically I have a image mapped out and when it is moused over it will pull data from that specific id from the table and display it. I have it all working statically and want to use the DB.

Comment: how soon is this method going to he phased out in lieu of PDO? may want to provide PDO eventually as well.